# Insertion Sort on 1 M integer Elements? Is there a tweak to run it faster on my personal computer?

Tags: python-3.x, time-complexity, insertion-sort

I have been working on Insertion sort to run a large number of elements around 1000000.I read the integers from file and passed them in insertion sort. My program started running on Monday evening and it was still running 6 hours later but when I woke up Tuesday morning somehow it crashed.Not sure if I was running in Jupyternotebook that made it crash or something else happened to my computer. I was wondering if there is some tweak around this.
1.How can I make sure my program does not crash again after waiting for 18+ hours like this when I am working with a number like 1M?
2.Is there way to make to run it faster?
Here is my code:

```
def insertionSort(score_ints1):
comparisions =0
for i in range(1,len(score_ints1)):
    value=score_ints1[i]
    j=i-1
    while j>=0:
        if value<score_ints1[j]:
            flag=True
        else:
            flag=False
        comparisions +=1
        if flag:
            score_ints1[j+1] = score_ints1[j]
            score_ints1[j] = value
            j=j - 1
        else:
            break
print("Number of comparisions :", comparisions)
print("Sorted list:", score_ints1)
```

I am also using a timeefficency() function to calculate the execution time of program.

Comment: Insertion sort is inherently going to be slow when the input size becomes large, see [this example](https://iyedb.github.io/algorithms/2014/05/09/sort-10-million.html) comparing simple quicksort and insertion sort implementations on 10 million integers.

Comment: A million elements is way too many for insertion sort. If you just need to sort them, use the built-in sort function; if you specifically want to know the number of comparisons that insertion sort *would* do, you can compute that without actually doing an insertion sort; it can be done using an [order statistic tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree) in O(n log n) time. If you want to estimate how much time in seconds insertion sort *would* take, you can extrapolate from smaller data points using the formula T(n) ~= cn^2 for some constant c.